# Common Lisp shared structure confusion

Tags: common-lisp, practical-common-lisp

I am reading the book Practical Common Lisp, and in the footnote5 of chapter22, page284, I saw a code snippet that made me confused.

I know that the variable list and tail have a list structure in common,
but I am confusing that since tail will be assigned the value of 'new' each time during the iteration, why (setf (cdr tail) new) would affect the state of the variable list？

```
(do ((list nil) (tail nil) (i 0 (1+ i)))
    ((> i 10) list)
  (let ((new (cons i nil)))
    (if (null list)
        (setf list new)
        (setf (cdr tail) new))
    (setf tail new)))

;;; => (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The invariant is that `tail` is always the last cons cell of `list`.

On each iteration, a new cons cell is created holding the new value as `car`.  The first time through, `list` is set to this cons cell, and `tail` too.  In all subsequent iterations, the new cons cell is appended by setting the `cdr` of the last cell to it, then setting `tail` to the new cell, to recreate the invariant.

After first iteration:

```
 [ 0 | nil ]
   ^- list
   ^- tail
```

After second:

```
 [ 0 | -]--->[ 1 | nil ]
   ^- list     ^- tail
```

Third:

```
 [ 0 | -]--->[ 1 | -]--->[ 2 | nil ]
   ^- list                 ^- tail
```

Answer (score 2):

The `do` form in your example keeps a pointer to the tail cons to make appending an element to the end of the list a cheap operation. Otherwise one would need to traverse the list all the time to find the last cons - for example by using `append`or `nconc`. Another way would be to collect new elements on the head and at the end to reverse the result list.

One would expect that the `LOOP` macro implements something efficient by transforming a higher level loop expression into efficient code.

The macro form

```
(loop for i upto 10 collect i)
```

might expand into something that works internally similar as your `do` example. The advantage of `loop` is that you don't need to implement the logic to track the tail, since that's what the macro should do for you.